# unable to create express-generator project using webstorm

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs. while creating nodejs express-generator form webstorm getting following error:

```
Error creating Node.js Express App. Cannot find /tmp/intellij-express-generator253/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
```

Answer (score 2):

To Add a bit more to @Weiyi Ma's answer

**Cause**

The issue is caused by recent changes in express-generator structure: express.js has been renamed to express-cli.js

**To Fix**

1.npm install -g express-generator

2. express project_name
3. cd project_name, npm install
4. in webstorm, File | open, choose project_name folder

Comment: i am facing this issue with webstorm only.

Answer (score 1):

```
  npm install -g express-generator
```

Then, the webstorm will work!